# InAppBrowser event.url always undefined

Tags: javascript, cordova, inappbrowser

Do you have any idea why event.url always undefined? This is for `loadstart` and `loadstop`.

The google page was displayed fine on pop up window.

```
var ref = window.open('http://google.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
ref.addEventListener('exit', function() { alert(event.type); });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var ref = window.open('http://google.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) { alert(event.type); });
```

The callback function is called when the event is fired. The function is passed an InAppBrowserEvent object.