# PhoneGap InAppBrowser URL undefined in loadstart

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm building a PhoneGap application with version 3.4.0 and testing on my iOS 7.1 iPad. I'm using the InAppBrowser object and hooking an event up to the `loadstart` event. Every time the `loadstart` event occurs and I try to access the url property on the even'ts object, it is undefined.

Here's my code:

```
    var authInAppBrowser = window.open(myOAuthUrl, '_blank', 'location=yes');
    $(authInAppBrowser).on('loadstart', function (e) {
        // e.url is always undefined
        window.alert(e.url);
    });
```

There's a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369519/inappbrowser-event-url-always-undefined) posing a similiar problem, but the answer doesn't resolve my issue. According to the [InAppBrowser documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowserEvent), the url property on the object is *"the URL that was loaded. (String)"*.

How can I receive the URL that was loaded in the InAppBrowser plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the native JavaScript way to add events made the URL appear:

```
var authInAppBrowser = window.open(authUrl, '_blank', 'location=yes');
authInAppBrowser.addEventListener('loadstart', function(e) {
    window.alert(e.url);
});
```